# Fourier transform of cos(x)/x

Tags: complex-integration, fourier-transform

I have to find a fourier transform of $f(x) = \cos(x)/x$.

This is what I have:

$$ F(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{2x}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})e^{-i\omega x}dx$$
$$ F(\omega) =  \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i(1-\omega)x}}{x}dx + \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i(-1-\omega)x}}{x}dx$$
Using integration in complex plane almost in the same manner as has been used in [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281870/fourier-transform-of-frac-sinxx) (I use fourier transform with minus sign), I obtain:

$I_1=i\pi$ for $\omega <1$ and $-i\pi$ for $\omega>1$

$I_2=i\pi$ for $\omega <-1$ and $-i\pi$ for $\omega >-1$

where $I_1$ and $I_2$ are first and second integral respectively. Combining these four results gives opposite sings [than needed](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier+transform&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22,+%22transformfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22cos(x)%2Fx%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22,+%22variable1%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22,+%22variable2%22%7D+-%3E%22w%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,+%22fourier+transform%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D).

Does anyone have a clue what's wrong? I'm pretty sure I've done integration correctly since both integrals are exactly the same as in $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ and I've got that one right.

Comment: You can write the result in this way $$\frac{1}{2} i \pi  (\text{sgn}(\omega-1)+\text{sgn}(\omega+1))$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right! but [wolfram](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform.html) uses as Fourier transform the following definition:
$$
F(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\mathrm e^{i\omega t}\mathrm d t
$$

Comment: I thought that may be the reason but than I recalled transforming  sin(x)/x with my definition gives the same answer as Wolfram does. That's probably because  sin(x)/x is an even function and cos(x)/x odd one.